Jupyter notebook running in Visual Studio Code cannot import local module, but the same jupyter server can
I started having this issue today, it was working fine last time I used it so I guess something was broken with one of the updates (not surprising).
I'm using VsCode in remote connected to a machine and running a jupyter notebook. I cannot import a module located in a subfolder of my home.

However, if I try to connect to the SAME EXACT server Vscode spawned to run its kernel (I tunnelled 8888 to my localhost and opened in the browser) everything is working.

I checked everything printed in the two notebooks: PATH, PYTHON_PATH, which python. Everything seems to be exactly the same. Needless to say I have many scripts running in the exact same folder where the notebook is located and they're doing just fine (as they've been doing for the past years). Whenever I open a normal python file the language server is working just fine and it finds all the imports.
I'm at a loss because I'm not understanding what is Vscode doing with the PATH or other parameters to mess up the import of local modules.
If I try to import something else (like import pandas as pd) it works as expected.
There must be something wrong when starting the kernel because the server seems to be spawned with the correct environment.

Hi, you can use the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+P to go to the command palette and input Select Interpreter to check if your python interperter kernel is correct. In the command palette, input Select Notebook Kernel to check whether the kernel of the jupyter notebook is correct.You can learn more about jupyter notebooks in the document.

This is obviously the first thing I tried...I'm quite versed in VsCode, Python environments and the Jupyter extentsion. There is some wrong option on my PC that is causing this behaviour on the remote because I cannot reproduce the same issue with my laptop.

You could check the subfolder containing the module you uploaded to the remote server for errors. Errors can also occur when uploading the wrong path in a jupyter notebook.

The problem was related to vscode not setting the right notebook file root. As workaround I had to specify
   "jupyter.jupyterCommandLineArguments": [
        "--notebook-dir='/dir/where/my/noteboook/imports/are/'"
    ],

manually.
All details are here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/15777 and the issue is https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8771
